# Eclipse: Add external project jar on deploying to tomcat

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, deployment

I am new to Java EE and I created a hello world project with jsp and servlets. I am able to run and view both jsp and servlets, but, when I reference an external project I am able to build but I cannot access it via the browser. I'm getting a `classNotFoundException` for the class being initialized from the external project.

I have figured out that the external project's jar is not being deployed, but how do I deploy it?

Can you please recommend a technique/technology that will be easy to run and debug?

I am running this within eclipse 3.7 with tomcat 7.

Thanks,

Comment: In Eclipse on your project properties, there is something called Project References try adding your external project and try it.

Comment: I've already done that. This makes the project compile but the external projects jar is not added in the war during deployment to tomcat

Comment: In your eclipse build path, there is a tab for "Projects" did you add your external project there ?

Comment: Yes I did. Like I said, if i wouldn't have done that the project wouldn't compile. But after it's deployed the jar of the referencing project is not included so I'm getting the ClassNotFoundException

Comment: Add the external project jar in tomcat/server/lib folder.

Comment: I though about that but I'm continously working on both projects. Plus it's a manual process to copy the jar from the previous project

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Sajan. I had to add the references in the Run Configuration for the jars to be deployed

Answer (score 2):

The following helped me to **deploy external jars** to Tomcat's project `WEB-INF/lib`:

> Right Click on Project > Properties > **Deployment Assembly** > Add >
> Archives from File System > Next > Add > Select the jars you want to
> add > Open > Finish

There are other options you can choose besides `Archives from File System` such as `Java Build Path Entries`.